# Mobile menu hides behind footer

Tags: html, css

Afternoon all,

I have been trying to figure out what I have done but can not for the life of me work it out. The navigation menu hides behind the footer instead of showing above it.

My code can be viewed [here](https://codepen.io/tomas5786/pen/ZExjJXo)

```
 /* Navigation Menu */
.menu {display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center; z-index: 1;}
.menu li a {display: block; padding: 15px 5px;}
.menu li.subitem a {padding: 15px;}
.toggle {order: 1; font-size: 20px;}
.item.button {order: 2;}
.item {order: 3; width: 100%; text-align: center; display: none}
.active .item {display: block;}
.button.secondary {border-bottom: 1px #4c9e9e solid;}

/* Footer */
.container-fluid {width: 100%; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;}
.bg {background-color: teal;}
.text-snow {color: #FAF6F6;}
.footer-setup {position:absolute; bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; padding-top: 3rem; z-index: 1;}
.row {display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px; text-align: center;}
.row-setup {padding-top: 3rem;}
.footer-row {flex: 1; margin-bottom: 3rem;}
.footer-row:first-child {margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;}
.footer-row {margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;}
.navbar-brand {display: inline-block; padding-top: 0.3125rem; padding-bottom: 0.3125rem; margin-right: 1rem; font-size: 1.25rem; line-height: inherit; white-space: nowrap;}
.brand-name {margin: -0.5rem 0 0.5rem; font-size: 2.5rem; line-height: 1.2;}
.navbar-brand span {color: #FFAA17;}
.navbar-brand p {margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 1rem;}
.follow {padding-top: 0.5rem; padding-bottom: 0.5rem;}
.d-flex {display: flex;}
.justify-start {justify-content:space-between;}
.row3, .row4 {display: none;}
```

Comment: simply add z-index more than the footer that will fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your `/* Footer */` in your CSS:

```
.footer-setup {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

try changing the `z-index` to a negative something like *-1* or change the `z-index` on your `nav` under `/* Basic Styling */`

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to the `nav` element.

```
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
```

See [Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).